# Angularjs - Pass argument to directive

Tags: angularjs, controller, arguments, directive

Im wondering if there is a way to pass an argument to a directive?

What I want to do is append a directive from the controller like this:

```
$scope.title = "title";
$scope.title2 = "title2";

angular.element(document.getElementById('wrapper')).append('<directive_name></directive_name>');
```

Is it possible to pass an argument at the same time so the content of my directive template could be linked to one scope or another?

here is the directive:

```
app.directive("directive_name", function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        transclude:true,
        template:'<div class="title"><h2>{{title}}</h3></div>',
        replace:true
    };
})
```

What if I want to use the same directive but with $scope.title2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem:

**Directive**

```
app.directive("directive_name", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: function(elem, attr){
           return '<div><h2>{{'+attr.scope+'}}</h2></div>';
        },
        replace: true
    };
})
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.building = function(data){
    var chart = angular.element(document.createElement('directive_name'));
    chart.attr('scope', data);
    $compile(chart)($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('wrapper')).append(chart);
  }
```

I now can use different scopes through the same directive and append them dynamically.

Comment: Can you explain this please?

Comment: What about directives which are restrict : A meaning attribute

Comment: @eranotzap It restricts directive to be used as _attribute_ only.

Comment: @Aivus that's very true. I ment what about the answer cases in which they are restricted to be used as attributes.

Answer (score 149):

You can pass arguments to your custom directive as you do with the builtin Angular-directives - by specifying an attribute on the directive-element:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('wrapper'))
       .append('<directive-name title="title2"></directive-name>');
```

What you need to do is define the `scope` (including the argument(s)/parameter(s)) in the factory function of your directive. In below example the directive takes a `title`-parameter. You can then use it, for example in the `template`, using the regular Angular-way: `{{title}}`

```
app.directive('directiveName', function(){
   return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
         title: '@'
      },
      template:'<div class="title"><h2>{{title}}</h2></div>'
   };
});
```

Depending on how/what you want to bind, you have different options:

- `=` is two-way binding
- `@` simply reads the value (one-way binding)
- `&` is used to bind functions

In some cases you may want use an "external" name which differs from the "internal" name. With external I mean the attribute name on the directive-element and with internal I mean the name of the variable which is used within the directive's scope.

For example if we look at above directive, you might not want to specify another, additional attribute for the title, even though you internally want to work with a `title`-property. Instead you want to use your directive as follows:

```
<directive-name="title2"></directive-name>
```

This can be achieved by specifying a name behind the above mentioned option in the scope definition:

```
scope: {
    title: '@directiveName'
}
```

Please also note following things:

- The HTML5-specification says that custom attributes (this is basically what is all over the place in Angular applications) should be prefixed with `data-`. Angular supports this by stripping the `data-`-prefix from any attributes. So in above example you could specify the attribute on the element (`data-title="title2"`) and internally everything would be the same.
- Attributes on elements are always in the form of `<div data-my-attribute="..." />` while in code (e.g. properties on scope object) they are in the form of `myAttribute`. I lost lots of time before I realized this.
- For another approach to exchanging/sharing data between different Angular components (controllers, directives), you might want to have a look at services or directive controllers.
- You can find more information on the [Angular homepage (directives)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: `@` copies the value, for one-way binding there's `<`. `<directive-name="title2">`? O.o Is that legal?

Answer (score 7):

You can try like below:

```
app.directive("directive_name", function(){
return {
    restrict:'E',
    transclude:true,
    template:'<div class="title"><h2>{{title}}</h3></div>',
    scope:{
      accept:"="
    },
    replace:true
  };
})
```

it sets up a two-way binding between the value of the 'accept' attribute and the parent scope.

And also you can set two way data binding with property: '='

For example, if you want both key and value bound to the local scope you would do:

```
  scope:{
    key:'=',
    value:'='
  },
```

For more info,
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

So, if you want to pass an argument from controller to directive, then refer this below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/y85Ft/7/

Hope it helps..

Comment: Im not sure I understand how Im supposed to pass the argument from the controller

Comment: I have updated an answer with fiddle, please refer that and hope it gives some idea..

Comment: I found something which work differently (updated my question) thanks!

Comment: works for scalar arguments, but not for objects, arrays or functions. :/

Answer (score 5):

### Controller code

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.person = {
        name:"sangeetha PH",
       address:"first Block"
    }
}]);
```

### Directive Code

```
myApp.directive('searchResult',function(){
   return{
       restrict:'AECM',
       templateUrl:'directives/search.html',
       replace: true,
       scope:{
           personName:"@",
           personAddress:"@"
       }
   } 
});
```

USAGE

File :**directives/search.html** 
content:

```
<h1>{{personName}} </h1>
<h2>{{personAddress}}</h2>
```

the File where we use directive

```
<search-result person-name="{{person.name}}" person-address="{{person.address}}"></search-result>
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert the var msg in the click event with scope.$apply to make the changes to the confirm, based on your controller changes to the variables shown in ng-confirm-click therein.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-confirm-click="You are about to send {{quantity}} of {{thing}} selected? Confirm with OK" confirmed-click="youraction(id)" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock">Send</button>




app.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
  function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
        element.on('click', function(event) {
          var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure? Click OK to confirm.";
          if (window.confirm(msg)) {
            scope.$apply(clickAction)
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button my-directive="push">Push to Go</button>

app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
         link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                elm.bind('click', function(event) {

                    alert("You pressed button: " + event.target.getAttribute('my-directive'));
                });
        }
    };
});
```

here is what I did

I'm using directive as html attribute and I passed parameter as following in my HTML file. `my-directive="push"` And from the directive I retrieved it from the Mouse-click event object. `event.target.getAttribute('my-directive')`.