# Pass argument to directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to pass argument to directive in angularjs.

I found some thread on stackoverflow [Angularjs - Pass argument to directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409460/angularjs-pass-argument-to-directive)

But it is not helped me.

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('datePicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="modelValue">',
        scope: {
            modelValue: '=',
            format: '@',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, form) {
            $(element).datepicker({
                dateFormat: format,
            });
        }
    }
})
```

**Element:**

```
<date-picker model-value="salary.month" format='MM-YYYY'></date-picker>
```

Here I want to use `format` as attribute to pass `directive`, So I can use same `date-picker` directive with different format.

I have tried with above code example,model value is working but format is not working.

Please help me to find solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `scope.format` to retrieve the value of the format attribute

```
link: function (scope, element, form) {
    $(element).datepicker({
        dateFormat: scope.format,
    });
}
```