# Angular js directive and restrict option

Tags: angularjs

i was reading a write up on directive from this url https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

```
The restrict option is typically set to:

    'A'     - only matches attribute name
    'E'    - only matches element name
    'C'    - only matches class name
    'M'    - only matches comment

<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <my-customer></my-customer>
</div>

angular.module('docsRestrictDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
  };
});
```

### template html file

```
Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}
```

please help me to understand what is the meaning of **restrict: 'E'**, ?

i am looking for a example where restrict will be **A or C**

please show me the usage of restrict: **'A' and C**

also tell me how could i pass **multiple argument to directives** ?

thanks

Comment: So you've posted the answer along with the question. What don't you understand - Is it the part of the actual implementation of the directive inside the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> please help me to understand what is the meaning of restrict: 'E', ?

The 'E' restriction will match by element name:

```
<my-customer></my-customer>
```

> i am looking for a example where restrict will be A or C
>
> please show me the usage of restrict: 'A' and C

The 'A' restriction will match by an element attribute:

```
<div my-customer=""></div>
```

The 'C' restriction will match by a class:

```
<div class="my-customer"></div>
```

> also tell me how could i pass multiple argument to directives ?

It depends on your requirements, but one simple way is using an isolated scope:

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
       arg1: "@",
       arg2: "@"
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
  };
});

<my-customer arg1="first" arg2="second"></my-customer>
```

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409460/angularjs-pass-argument-to-directive) gives a pretty good explanation of this process.

Comment: just seen your code arg1: `"@",` is it mandatory to assign scope property with @ sign ? can't it be a empty like `arg1: "",` please guide. thanks for answer.

Comment: what is the meaning of `SO` you said here.

Comment: "@" is a type flag, it means accept a string value. Other options are "=" to bind to another Angular scope variable and "&" to accept a javascript function.

Comment: "SO" is a shorthand (lazy) way of typing "StackOverflow".

Comment: one request can u redirect me to article which discuss the usage of `@ = &` in much details with many examples.

Comment: Sure, this infographic explains the basic differences: http://onehungrymind.com/infographic-understanding-angularjs-isolated-scope/ and it links to these examples: http://plnkr.co/edit/waso3F?p=preview. I found the best way to get a feel for scope isolation to try it out and have an experiment yourself.

Answer (score 3):

let say you have a directive 'myDirective'

if in restrict you have only C you can only use it as classes like this :

```
<div class="my-directive"></div>
```

If it's A it's as attribute :

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

If it's E it's as element

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

TO pass argument you generaly se attributes :

```
<div my-directive my-first-argument="toto" my-second-argument="titi"></div>
```

To get the value you have to way :

```
use the attr provided in link function
use the scope with one way or two way binding.
```

Personnaly i prefer the attribute approach when it comme to directive, element after and class in last. I have already bootstrap based on classes i don't want to clash with it.

Comment: u said this "use the attr provided in link function
use the scope with one way or two way binding." this is not clear to me bcoz i am new in NG. so would discuss it with posting two sample code. one with attr keyword usage and one with scope. looking for further help.

Answer (score 1):

`restrict` is key to be used in DDO (Directive Definition Object) to inform what it Would be in view

for Example in DDO (Directive Definition Object)

1. Directive with `restrict:E` (Element)

   **Directive**

   ```
   app.directive('my-directive',function(){
            return {
               restrict: 'E', //means HTML Element
               ...
             };
   });
   ```

   so directive in View for `restrict:'E'` as Element in HTML element as below

**view**

```
<myDirective></myDirective>
```

2. Directive with `restrict:A` (Attributes)

**Directive**

```
 app.directive('my-directive',function(){
     return {
        restrict: 'A', //means HTML attribute
        ...
      };
     })
```

so directive in View for `restrict:'A'` as attribute in HTML element as below

**view**

```
<div myDirective></div>
```

3. Directive with `restrict:'C'` (class)

**Directive**

```
 app.directive('my-directive',function(){
     return {
        restrict: 'C', //means HTML attribute
        ...
      };
     })
```

so directive in View for `restrict:'C'` as class in HTML element as below

**view**

```
<div class="myDirective"></div>
```

you can use Isolate scope (doesn't inherit from its parents scope) or you can pass variables to attributes which depends on your implementation both can used in directive's `link` and `controller`

for isolate scope DDO will be as

```
<my-directive variable1="hello" variable2="world" variable3="call()"></my-directive>



app.directive('myDirective',function(){
         restrict:E,
        scope:{
           variable1:'@variable1',
           variable2:'=varialbe2',
           variable3:'&variable3'
          }
    })
```

Or you can also pass data through attributes and access them using attrs in Directive's link Function and $attrs DI in Directives Controller

Comment: here scope has 3 property call variable1,variable2 and variable3. u assign some with @ sign, some with & sign some with = sign that is not clear. these signs are mandatory ?

Comment: u said "you can also pass data through attributes and access them using attrs in Directive's link Function" would post a easy sample code where pass data will be capture by using attrs ? thanks

Comment: @Mou Those signs are required if you want isolate scope for your directive , which indeed acts a reusable components which is trivial for large applications.we can pass properties from parent scope to the directive based on the needs. '@' for one-way binding ,'=' for two way binding and '&' method binding.

Comment: @Mou for passing data through attributes here is https://plnkr.co/edit/Y3jBbIQmWWd7oYh0YeR3?p=preview  for it

Comment: @Mou here is directive with isolated scope http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview