# Passing attribute value to directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Directive usage**

`<my-directive my-attr='StackOverflow'></my-directive>`

**Directive definiton**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($scope){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'I want to print the attribute value',
    controller: function($scope){
      // I also want to access the attribute value here.
    }
  };
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `scope: true` write,

```
scope: {
  myattr: '@'
}
```

Then `myattr` will be available in `$scope`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shreyas_a/chpqfxvb/)

> Make sure to use small casing, somehow using any other casing like pascal or camel causes problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass values to directive using scope.

your code can be written something like

```
   app.directive('myDirective', function($scope){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      Scope:{
        myAttr:'='
      },
      template: 'I want to print the attribute value: and here is your value: {{myAttr}}',
      controller: function($scope){
       // I also want to access the attribute value here.
        console.log($scope.myAttr);
      }
```

};
});

and usage is same

```
<my-directive my-attr='StackOverflow'></my-directive>
```

Here is same question 
[Angularjs - Pass argument to directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409460/angularjs-pass-argument-to-directive)

Also you can find more information on usage of directive at 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Similar code is working for me, I don't know what's causing the issue.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle!