# How to access index in a component called in ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following files. This is code in node-list.html

```
<tbody sv-node-list-item ng-repeat="item in items" />
```

And this is code in node-list-item.html.

```
<tr><td>{{$index}}</td></tr>
```

Basically node-list-item is rendered for each iteration of the ng-repeat of the node-list.html file. I need to access the index of the item from the parent i.e. node-list.html in node-list-item.html I have been researching this for quiet some time but am not able to do so. Please help. I am using angular1 i.e. angularjs. This is the directive code in node-list-item.js

```
function directive() { return { templateUrl: "partials/node-list-item.html" };}
module.directive("svNodeListItem",[ directive ]);
```

Comment: can you create a plunker please?

Comment: The node-list-item directive would need to accept the index as an attribute. Show the code for that directive

Comment: I added directive code if there is any more stuff that needs to be added please do tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the `node-list.html`:(You need to send index to the node-list-item directive)

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" sv-node-list-item index="{{$index}}"/>
```

Then change your `sv-node-list-item` directive to this:

```
function directive() { 
    return { 
        scope: {
           index: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: "partials/node-list-item.html" 
    };
}
module.directive("svNodeListItem",[ directive ]);
```

And finally your `node-list-item.html` to this:

```
<tr><td>{{index}}</td></tr>
```

For more information about ng-repeat check the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and for directive variables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409460/angularjs-pass-argument-to-directive).

Comment: trbody and tr are not part of the same file. I wouldn't have this problem if they were. I am using this node-list-item.html component at 5 or six other places where i need the same index from the parent that has ng-repeat. And node-list-item happens to be a 200 line code which i cannot put separately at all those places

Comment: @rexroxm the sv-node-list-item is a directive right? can you put your javascript code please?

Comment: yes it is a directive. it attaches node-list-item for each iteration.

Comment: @rexroxm ok. But can you add the code from the directive to the question so I could help you better?

Comment: I added directive code if there is any more stuff that needs to be added please do tell.

Comment: @rexroxm I mad changes the answer. Please, check out the differences and see if solves your problem. :D